# Separating a series of links with a divider, in a dropdwn menu option

Tags: html, css

I would like to add a divider - a simple solid line - to separate a series of links in a dropdown menu option. I'm not entirely certain as to how to go about though. I have the below coding but it isn't creating the impression that I desire. Also Im unable to understand how I would then customise this 'divider' to look the way I would ideally want it to appear.

```
<li><a href='#'>Social</a>
<ul> 
<li><a href='http://www.pinterest.com/blankesque'>Pinterest</a></li>
<li><a href='http://www.twitter.com/itsblankesque.com'>Twitter</a></li>
<li><a href='http://www.bloglovin.com/people/aladyinwhite-8315551'>Bloglovin</a></li>
<li><a href='http://www.instagram.com/blankesque/blankesquexo'>Instagram</a></li>
<ul class='dropdown-divider' aria-labelledby='dropdownMenuDivider'>
<li><a href='mailto:blankesque@hotmail.com'>Email</a></li>
<li role='separator' class='divider'></li></ul>
</ul></li>
```

Any help in this matter would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Iram

Comment: li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

Answer (score 0):

There is no Css there, so i went ahead and did something there.

```
 ul li {display:block;margin-right:2px;
 min-width:60px;
 text-align: center;
 height: 25px;
 border-bottom:1px solid black;
 }
```

Check the link, let me know, do you want it to be displayed horizontaly or as it is now, vertically?

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/RWEVPW